# Understanding Slope Line and Flow Direction in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, slope, flow-direction

I would like to create a Flow Direction (Polyline - not raster) which needs to follow slope direction (as arrow in picture I attached)

[image]

I'm working in mike urban (SWMM Model) and the software assign catchmente slope in according with flow direction. Specifically it need as inpunt a DEM Raster and Flow direction line. The polygon in this img rapresent the sub-catchment and in order to address the flow in each specific subcatchment-nodes I need to assign slope.

Can you suggest me how I can work in ArcMap to get them?

Comment: what do the polygons represent?

Comment: Slope raster plays no role in it.

Comment: I'm working in mike urban (SWMM Model) and the software assign catchmente slope in according with flow direction. Specifically it need as inpunt a DEM Raster and Flow direction line. The polygon in this img rapresent the sub-catchment and in order to address the flow in each specific subcatchment-nodes I need to assign slope.